# How to use JQuery to select a hidden form field value that is part of an array of hidden form field values?

Tags: jquery, html, hidden-field

I am having trouble selecting a hidden form field value that is a part of an array of hidden form field values having the same name. Here's what one element of the array looks like:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ProductId must be a number." data-val-required="The ProductId field is required." id="OrderItemViewModels_2__ProductId" name="OrderItemViewModels[2].ProductId" type="hidden" value="3" />
```

I have tried selecting it several different ways in JQuery, such as:

```
$('#OrderItemViewModels[2].ProductId').val());
```

and..

```
$('#OrderItemViewModels\\[2\\].ProductId').val());
```

Neither of which worked. I've also tried a few other ways as well. So, I tried some of the suggestions from below, hoping to just print the values in an alert. I tried these:

```
alert('valueDirect2=' + $('#OrderItemViewModels_2__ProductId')).val();
alert('valueDirect1=' + $('input[name="OrderItemViewModels[2].ProductId"]')).val();
```

This results in printing valueDirect2=[Object object] in both cases. Why? What is wrong here?

I'm at a loss as to how to get these values. Any help?

Comment: none of those are selecting it by its actual ID of `OrderItemViewModels_2__ProductId`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need this to be dynamic, i.e. change on the fly which `input` field is selected? If so, you'll need to add a variable into the middle of your selector.

If you modify your existing code like this, it'll work:

```
$('#OrderItemViewModels_2__ProductId').val();
```

Your two samples didn't work because you're formatting your selector string similar to how the `name` attribute, but the `#` prefix tells jQuery to look for an `id` attribute.

It is possible to select an element by name as well, which would look like this:

```
$('input[name="OrderItemViewModels[2].ProductId"]').val();
```

In your `alert` examples, you're seeing `[Object object]` because the `$` syntax in jQuery is a shortcut for calling the jQuery function. What you're really doing is this:

```
jQuery('input[name="OrderItemViewModels[2].ProductId"]').val();
```

It's just a plain old function call. The `S` is a convenient shorthand. You're calling a function and passing in a string, which is the selector that jQuery will evaluate.

Your selector wasn't returning anything because it was formatted incorrectly, so you were ending up printing the `.val()`, or value, of the jQuery function itself. It's a little confusing until you have a good conceptual grasp of how jQuery works.

To make your selector dynamic, just splice strings together around the variable that contains the number of the `input` you want to select:

```
$('input[name="OrderItemViewModels[' + myVariable + '].ProductId"]').val();
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshearl/MNLFM/2/) that illustrates both options.

Comment: Okay, so I see the error between trying to query by name and ID. But I am still not getting what I expect to see either way. And yes, I need it to be dynamic (the '2' will be fetched another way and that already works). But I figured I'd try to just get this working first, and it's not.

Comment: Updated my answer to address your questions. Let me know if you have more. :)

Comment: I see my error Josh. Had a parenthesis in the wrong spot. Nice answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="OrderItemViewModels['+ index +'].ProductId"]').val(); // index = 0,1,2...
```

OR

```
$('#OrderItemViewModels_'+ index +'__ProductId').val(); // index = 0,1,2...
```